# Large spin system and Lipkin-Meshkov-Glick (LMG) model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin-models

I read about spin systems like LMG originally modelled in order to test the validity of approximation techniques in quantum many-body systems. But it's also used to delicately understand the quantum criticality and the magnetic properties of atoms and molecules. The advantage of large spin system is that there is a classical limit and easy to analyse many phenomena. Classical limit is obtained for $S\gg 1$ where the commutator bracket of scaled spin operators tends towards zero
$$[s_x,s_y]=i\frac{\hbar}{S}s_z\rightarrow 0$$
Where $s_j=S_j/S$. But is it not mean that the quantum fluctuation is decreasing to zero, if it is true then how quantum phase transition occurs in these systems as quantum phase transition is mediated primarily by quantum fluctuation?

Answer (score 1):

The LMG model may in fact be mapped onto a system of two species of bosons, with the total number of bosons being $N=2S$, see for instance page 5 of thesis [Thermalisation
of a two-species condensate coupled to a bosonic bath](https://scholar.sun.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10019.1/106032/louw_thermalisation_2019.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). As such, in this case, taking the large $S$ limit, is just equivalent to taking the thermodynamic limit in the model.

A quantum phase transition just means a non-analyticity in the ground state energy (i.e. energy at zero temperature), which one may see in this model by considering a semi-classical treatment, see page 28 of the aforementioned thesis.